# WCF help page URLs remember wrong base addresses

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, web-config

We've just deployed a WCF app to a load balanced environment. We noticed that for the help page (enabled by `<webHttp helpEnabled="true" />` in the  web.config) whichever url is used to access the help page first is the one that will be used to describe the relative urls across all environments. So if we hit the `help/operations/GetWidgetList` page through the externally facing url all the relative urls and the Widget List page's header will reference the externally facing url. If we visit the `help/operations/GetGadget` page through localhost from one of the servers behind the load balancer, the Gadget page will display all localhost urls regardless of how that help page is accessed.

First Time:
[image: localhost first]

All subsequent calls:
[image: means localhost everywhere]

Restarting the app in IIS seems to reset the state of this problem, but it will crop up again if pages are accessed first at the wrong url. Is there a way to define a canonical base url that the help page should always use? We've explored setting `baseAddress` in the `web.config` but if I understand correctly, since we're hosting in IIS those attributes are ignored.